# How can we stop journalling on InterSystems IRIS instance?

Tags: transactions, intersystems, intersystems-iris

Doing DISABLE^%NOJRN pauses journalling for the process.
I need to stop/pause journalling for the whole instance. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This completely stops journaling:

```
ClassMethod StopJournaling()
{
    new $namespace
    set $namespace = "%SYS"
    set x = $$INT^JRNSTOP(.err)
    if (x=0) {
        write "Stopping journaling error code " _ err
    } else {
        write "Stopped journaling"
    }
    write !
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this code written in?

Comment: Is it [ObjectScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cach%C3%A9_ObjectScript)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes. Well, it's called `InterSystems ObjectScript` now, but the answer is valid for both.

Answer (score 1):

You could always go to the System Management portal and edit each database that you are interested in and disable journaling.  I know it's not specifically what you asked but it could help.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen, this works but it's a manual way, I was looking for some procedure to call

Comment: In SYS.Database there is a method called DisableJournaling, additionally there is a EnableJournaling.